# Are items in question blocks in Mario Maker 2 globally loaded?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

This is a pretty basic question. I don't have the game and just want to know this so I can design a level. In short, I want to know if an object in a question block is still loaded  if it is past the loading zone.

Comment: Why would it make a difference?

Comment: By loading zone, do you mean the start screen on a level? Question blocks can hold items regardless of where they're placed in a level, or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: @QuestionMarks By loading zone, I mean the area around Mario (vertically or horizontally) where things are loaded.

Comment: Globally loaded refers to the areas outside of this zone where objects are still loaded.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe Globally loaded objects contribute to the entity limit.

Comment: I think this question has been difficult to answer because your meaning of 'exist' in terns of items in question blocks is vague in this context. If you could clarify that, I think that'd add a lot to the quality of this question.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Exists = Loaded

Answer (score 5):

### Items do *not* count towards the active Item Limit while inside blocks, regardless of if they're in the loading zone or not

Powerups have a 100 item limit (per area, so 200 per level). Once you hit that limit, you're prevented from placing any more, but by placing the powerups into item blocks (or Bullet Bill launchers), you're potentially able to place up to another 2000 powerups. If there are 100 active items in the loading zone though, hitting the item block will just show a 'poof' effect as nothing comes out. Comsuming powerups within the loading zone when the limit has been reached will allow you to once again obtain items from blocks.

Gif demonstration below:

[image: Items poof at limit]

Here you can see that there are 100 stars placed in the area to the right, and I'm unable to place any more powerups. By adding the stars to the question block, the stars no longer count towards the entity limit, and I'm able to add powerups till I hit the entity limit again.

Trying to get the items from the question block while the 100 powerups are in the loading screen causes the new powerups to 'poof' and not appear when the question block is hit.

If the powerup limit has not been reached within the loading zone while it has been reached for the level, hitting a block will give the item inside. 
Additionally, if the item entity limit has been reached *outside* the loading zone, you are still able to get items from blocks, and in the case of moving items (such as stars and mushrooms), if they move into an area where items have been placed to reach the entity limit all within the loading zone, you'll actually be able to **exceed** the entity limit (I was able to get 103 stars in the loading zone [with that trick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgavV.jpg)).

---

[Source Youtube Video for entity information](https://youtu.be/QnvXVe0hNXo?t=161)

Comment: I don’t think that’s what he was asking....

Comment: @QuestionMarks This is not what I was asking for. What I want to know is if items in questions blocks still count towards the entity limit beyond the current loading zone.

Comment: Items in question blocks do not count towards the active item entity limit, regardless of if they're in the loading zone or not. The gif also demonstrates this by having 100 stars on screen even with the item blocks loaded with stars

Comment: @QuestionMarks Okay! I see now. Still, this does not directly correspond to my question. What I was looking for was whether or not items exist in question blocks beyond the loading zone. What you have shown is that they do not exist at all in blocks and are created after the block is hit. This is what you need to change the answer to.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Why can you get more than "100 items" in the loading zone? Your answer doesn't account for that.

Comment: @BrendonShaw Items that are placed directly on the map (not inside blocks) don't 'poof' like items inside blocks do when the entity limit is reached within the loading zone. Only reason why is that's how the game was designed.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Then how was the game designed? Why do they 'poof'? Why do items in question blocks not count toward the entity limit? Once you answer or at least try to answer these questions, I will count your answer as right.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2: Turns out I was a little bit wrong with my knowledge, but also right with my answer; it depends on the item you're looking for. I tested it in SMB1 and mushrooms will stay loaded in but a POW block will disappear. Fire Flower and the Star stays, whereas a Goomba will despawn. So for whatever you're trying to spawn from the ? block, you'll have to test it out in a world and see.

=======

If your question is: Does an item that comes out of a ? Block stay globally loaded after popping out, then I am pretty sure the answer is no, unless it ends up on something that forces it to stay globally loaded like an icicle. Using icicles will force whatever is on it to be globally loaded so it would give a false positive.

You can try testing it real quick, honestly. It's super easy. Create a blank slate level and have the ? block spit out a mushroom or something, and have the mushroom get stuck in like a 1 block gap right next to the ? block somehow. Run like a mile away, come back and check. If it's there, it's globally loaded. If not, then it's not. Just make sure you trap it using like.. Normal ground or something (see above about icicles).

As a side note, you can also try having the item stay stuck on the ? block it came from as well to test and see if THAT makes it globally loaded as well. Still, I'm pretty sure that's not the case, but I don't know as I've never tried.

Edit: Just in case I missed the question.. If you are at the sprite limit and you are remote activating a ? block to spawn an item, it does count towards the sprite limit. Your item will not spawn and will poof like the items do in the gif posted. If the sprite limit is not reached yet, then check the results of the test above I gave you and see how that goes. I'd test it myself but I gotta get my Switch handy.

Comment: He said he doesn't have the game so is there a way for him to even test any of this? If not he needs you to do the testing for him. Also a lot of stuff changed from Mario Maker 1 to Mario Maker 2. You'd have to try to test it in Mario Maker 2 to be certain about any of this. And one last thing instead of adding fixes to the post at the bottom edit out the incorrect information and replace it with the correct information. That makes the post easier to read.

Comment: I didn't see anywhere in this that he doesn't have the game. I'm looking through and still don't see it, which is why I suggested it in the first place. I'm more than happy to test for him, but it all depends on what he's doing and needs to let someone know.

Comment: @KaraNoelle I was wondering if items in question blocks were globally loaded. Turns out they don't exist at all.

Comment: @KaraNoelle Oh! I can see why you answered this way. My title just asked for question blocks. In the description I make it clear that I am talking about items in question blocks too.

Comment: @KaraNoelle The second sentence. "I don't have the game and just want to know this so I can design a level. "